# why does ReadXmlSchema create extra "ID" column

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, dataset

Given an XSD file, code like the following produces an extra (and unwanted) column in both DataTables in the returned DataSet.

```
ds.ReadXmlSchema(s);
```

Both DataTables have an Order_Id column; other columns perfectly match the XSD.

Has anyone else seen this before?

XSD file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="Order">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType msdata:AutoIncrement="false">
            <xs:attribute name="itemId" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
            <xs:attribute name="stockCode" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="stockCodeType" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="Quantity" type="xs:unsignedLong" />
            <xs:attribute name="ProductIdX" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
            <xs:attribute name="legalEntity" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="countryOfIssue" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="branchSystem" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="accountId" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="settlementDate" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="tradeDate" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="partyCode" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="userId" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="OrderId" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
      <xs:attribute name="StrategyId" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="ActivityId" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should have a look at [**Deriving DataSet Relational Structure from XML Schema (XSD)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bfdchewb.aspx). This article points out that

> In general, for each **complexType child element** of a schema element, a
>   **table is generated** in the DataSet. The table structure is determined
>   by the definition of the complex type.
>
> ...
>
> However, a table is only created for a top-level complexType element
>   when the **complexType element is nested inside another complexType**
>   element, in which case the **nested complexType element is mapped** to a
>   **DataTable** within the DataSet.

So basically in this case `ReadXML(...)` *will create two tables*

1. Order
2. Item

As **Item complexType** is **nested within Order complexType** a *relation* between those two tables will be *generated* too. To be able to create this relation a **new column Order_id will be included**.

**EDIT**

Have a further look at [**Generating DataSet Relations for XSD**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk6y3s8y.aspx). Within this article you will find this:

> The **msdata:Relationship annotation** allows you to explicitly specify
>   parent-child relationships between elements in the schema that are not
>   nested. The following example shows the structure of the Relationship
>   element.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="Order">
     ... your definition goes here!
 </xs:element>
 <xs:annotation>
   <xs:appinfo>
     <msdata:Relationship name="OrderItemRelation"
      msdata:parent="Order"
      msdata:child="Item" 
      msdata:parentkey="OrderID"
      msdata:childkey="ANY_COLUMN_IN_NESTED_COMPLEX_TYPE"/>
   </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
</xs:schema>
```

So you can **modify what column will be used** for referring inner to outer complexType but you **can not prevent this functionality**!

Comment: thank you! this is helpful, but is there a way to circumvent this? i.e., to avoid automatically adding in this Order_Id column in the generated DataSet?

Comment: added some more information on how to modify created relationship

Comment: Excellent information (+1). An improvement I could think of is to make it clearer that the issue is really that of moving from a **hierarchical** model to an **entity-relationship** model: the implicit relationship between nested entities must be now explicitly cared for. Also an interesting fact is that if the XML would've contain the `ANY_COLUMN_IN_NESTED_COMPLEX_TYPE` for Item in your example, then the XML would contain a lot of redundant data and it would also require a key/keyref to ensure that inconsistencies between values are spotted by XSD.